# System.AccessViolationException in OracleCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters

Tags: .net, ado.net, oracle10g

Connection is open, package is valid, procedure exists.

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in Oracle.DataAccess.DLL
System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OpsSql.ExecuteNonQuery(IntPtr opsConCtx, IntPtr& opsErrCtx, IntPtr& opsSqlCtx, IntPtr& opsDacCtx, IntPtr opsSubscrCtx, Int32& isSubscrRegistered, OpoSqlValCtx*& pOpoSqlValCtx, OpoSqlRefCtx& pOpoSqlRefCtx, IntPtr[] pOpoPrmValCtx, OpoPrmRefCtx[] pOpoPrmRefCtx, OpoMetValCtx*& pOpoMetValCtx, Int32 prmCnt)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(OracleCommand command)
```

Comment: This sounds like a bug in the Oracle DLL - report to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-installed client, problem went away.